# lp prints blank pages for pure text file

Tags: linux, rhel, printing, gedit, printer

Printing a text file through lp result in blank page while printing same file through gedit works fine.

lp is able to print pdf and jpg image files, but not text file.

On further looking in to issue I found similar kind of issues are reported based on paps usage. So I removed paps package. Text files starts printing file but paps is used for UTF-8 handling so now UTF-8 characters are not rending properly.
I used HP Officejet pro 8000 and HP Officejet pro 251dw series printers.

How gedit is processing the file for printing, I think it also uses lp command down the line.